# Applying Camera Transformations to OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I'm attempting to create a Camera class for a 3D OpenGL project. However I cannot figure out how to actually apply the camera to my scene. I have these Camera functions (amongst others):

```
void Camera::update(){
    glm::vec3 direction(cos(_verticalAngle) * sin(_horizontalAngle), sin(_verticalAngle), cos(_verticalAngle) * cos(_horizontalAngle));

    glm::vec3 right = glm::vec3(sin(_horizontalAngle - 3.14f/2.0f), 0, cos(_horizontalAngle - 3.14f/2.0f));

    glm::vec3 up = glm::cross(right, direction);

    _projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(_FoV, float(VIEWPORT_X) / float(VIEWPORT_Y), 0.1f, 250.0f);
    _viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(_position, _position + direction, up);
}
glm::mat4 Camera::getProjectionMatrix(){
    return _projectionMatrix;
}
glm::mat4 Camera::getViewMatrix(){
    return _viewMatrix;
}
```

They were created from a tutorial, I'm not sure if they work though since I can't test them. What I want to do is get OpenGL to use the view and projection matrices to simulate a camera. How exactly do I tell OpenGL to use those projection and view matrices, so that it properly simulates a camera separate from model's transformations? I'm aware OpenGL will not accept glm matrices by default, but I have seen this type of thing in a few tutorials:

```
glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();
glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
```

but glUniformMatrix4fv (which I think applies the camera transforms?) makes no sense to me. It always has something to do with shaders, which I have none of. I simply have a wireframe test mesh currently. Could someone provide me a code snippet for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about using GLM, but I can help with the regular OpenGL part.

glUniformMatrix4fv updates a 4x4 uniform matrix at the location specified by MatrixID in a particular shader program.

I recommend working through [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/), which is excellent as both a reference and guide.

For a discussion of how these uniforms are used within the GLSL shader program see:
[Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming - Chapter 3](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Positioning/Tut03%20A%20Better%20Way.html)

Comment: This is a fantastic resource. Thank you.

Comment: If anybody is interested in running the Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming tutorials on OS X, I have an Xcode+GLFW3 port here: https://github.com/rsanchezsaez/gltut-glfw (wip)

Answer (score 2):

use glLoadMatrixf() if you are not using shaders, if you want just multiply current matrix use glMultMatrixf(), current matrix mode can switch use glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION or GL_MODELVIEW); for example(this is your code):

```
lm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();

//setup projection matrix for opengl
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMultMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(ProjectionMatrix));
or:
glMultMatrixf(&ProjectionMatrix[0][0]);
```

EDIT:

if you want to apply transform to your model:(model_view are combined in fixed function)

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(&viewMatrix[0][0]); 
glMultMatrixf(&modelTransform[0][0]);   //model * view
Draw_your_model();
```

you might need to set your transform like this :
glm::translate(modelTransform,-10,-10,-10);  so your model will be at (10,10,10)

Comment: Alright, this applies my projection matrix... How would I apply the view matrix?

Comment: glMatrixMode is depreciated as of OpenGL 3.0. Since it sounds like the OP is just getting started it would be wise not to point them towards depreciated functionality.

Comment: Deprecated? Ain't that something. From what I understand I guess transform and pretty much everything are handled through shaders now?

Answer (score 0):

Based at your code you should do the following :

```
glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = inverse(getViewMatrix());//view(camera) must be inverse(if you don't already do it)
glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(MVP));//use value_ptr method to pass matrix pointer
```

Also to set proper camera matrix I would suggest using lookAt() GLM build in method to calculate eye, dir ,up and compose those into final matrix for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no such variable as MatrixID. I have no shaders implemented at the moment.

Comment: But if you do it using fixed pipeline then you don't need calculating your matrices manually at all.Search for tutorials.I have never done fixed stuff so can\t really help here.